# How do I provide dynamic host names for all docker containers?

Tags: dns, docker

Currently, I have a single machine I'm starting to run docker images on.  What I want to do is have all containers accessible through a host name based upon the container name.  So, if I have container `C1` and `C2`, and the host for the docker server is `mydocker.local`, then `c1.mydocker.local` will point to container image `C1` and if I were to run `C3`, it would become available as `C3.mydocker.local`.

[docker-dns](https://www.npmjs.com/package/docker-dns) seems similar to what I'm trying to do, but the project hasn't been updated for 7 months and documentation was not enough for me to get it running.

This seems like a very common use case, but I have not been able to create the appropriate google query magic to find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [docker-gen](https://github.com/jwilder/docker-gen) to automatic update your host's `hosts` file, or create a `dns` service such as `Dnsmasq`.

Also I found an docker image called [dns-gen](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/jderusse/dns-gen/) which just using docker-gen and dnsmasq, might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

A you should use explicit linking if containers are going to depend on each other. This will update the etc hosts file inside the container to add IPs for each of the linked containers.

If you do want something something like [Rancher](http://rancher.com/) will give you a complete virtual private network in which each of the containers has its own IP. Rancher also supports services which will maintain DNS for all running containers. Bonus for using rancher is that it will work in a multi-host scenario as well.